# Normalization exercise

Tags: database, normalization

I made up an exercise to my self for improving my normalization skills.
I will describe the exercise and my solution.
**Please give me a feedback about any mistake you find on the way.**

---

The Relations from which I will conclude the Super-Keys and Candidate-Keys:

- {`A`,`C`} `->` {`B`,`D`}
- {`D`} `->` {`C`}
- {`A`} `->` {`D`}
- {`E`} `->` {`A`,`B`,`C`}

---

1. I will start with what relations I can conclude also:

   - {`A`,`C`} `->` {`B`}
   - {`A`,`C`} `->` {`D`} `->` {`C`}
   - {`A`} `->` {`D`} `->` {`C`}
   - {`E`} `->` {`A`,`B`,`C`}

In short:

- {`A`,`C`} `->` {`B`}
- {`A`} `->` {`D`} `->` {`C`}
- {`E`} `->` {`A`,`B`,`C`}

Agian, in short: (From the conclusion that {`A`} `->` {`C`} )

- {`A`} `->` {`B`}
- {`A`} `->` {`D`} `->` {`C`}
- {`E`} `->` {`A`,`B`,`C`}

---

2. Candidates - Keys: {`E`}
3. Primes: {`E`}
4. Non - Primes: {`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`}
5. Checking normalization rules:

   - 1NF - OK
   - 2NF - OK
   - 3NF - NOT OK, Examples:

     1. {`A`} `->` {`B`}
     2. {`A`} `->` {`D`} `->` {`C`}

---

6. Fixing 3NF rule:

I will split The above relation to 4 relations:

- {`E`} `->` {`A`}
- {`A`} `->` {`B`}
- {`A`} `->` {`D`}
- {`D`} `->` {`C`}

Comment: Do document it Sir for others to get better insight of Normalizations

Comment: Those are not "relations", they are FDs (functional dependencies) that hold in a relation/table. Also, you cannot determine CKs etc unless you know the set of all attributes of the relation. Also you need to know all the FDs, not just some. Maybe you mean that the set is a "cover", ie the only FDs that hold are the ones that hold when those hold. But if you didn't *mean* that you are confused.. Armstrong's axioms give all the FDs that hold, and there are many more than here. What process do you think you are following? Please tell us what you are using as a reference.

Comment: Hi @philipxy, yes I'm confuced :) I gave all the relations + the attributes are: `A` - `E`. I'm not following ant specific process because I dont know there is one.

Comment: There are literally dozens of academic textbooks free online & slides (.pdf/.ppt) & courses (eg stanford.edu). If you want us to give you feedback on something then you have to say what you wanted to achieve. But if you aren't trying to do something that is part of a correct procedure, or don't tell us what, then we can only point you to a reference. You're taking a course, what is its textbook? PS Edit clarifications into your question, not comments.

Comment: In RDBMS the term "Relation" has nothing to do with the relationships between tables. A relation is an mathematical term that refers to a table a table that meets certain specifications... More specifically, a relation is a table that satisfies 1NF.